# Search ArrayList objects by SQL queries in Java

Tags: sql, arraylist

My Apologies if this is a repeat question. any pointer to similar Q&A would also be fine.

Is there an API which can let me search thru list of Custom object like SQL. Currently I have implemented a feature to do regex which is implement using overriding toString() in each of object graph. These list of Objects are constructed from DB (5 tables / 2 different host) but massaged with Business usecase, so actual DB value will be somewhat different than what I have in list.

Answer (score 0):

In short: you can't.

Longer version: if you need SQL-like capability beyond things easily achievable with `for` loops, regexes, and the like, use a database! Databases can be very lightweight. Take a look at HSQLDB, SQLite, JavaDB/Derby, H2, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, got to know about [josql](http://josql.sourceforge.net/) from one of my friend. Haven't tried it so far. Will post my review after using it.